# Is beeilen always a reflexive verb?

Tags: verb, standard-german

*Sich beeilen* = to hurry up

Is it always a refliexive verb?

I have come across this sentence too:

> Sie eilten herbei. (They hurried up.)

Here *eilten* can also be used for "to hurry" and it does not require self reflexive pronoun?

Comment: I wrote something (maybe a little bit technical) about the subject here: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/55221/35111

Comment: What about "Sein Fehler beeilte das Unglueck." or "Sein Rauchen beeilte die Krankheit." or similar?

Answer (score 23):

Yes, *beeilen* is always reflexive in modern usage. You cannot say **er beeilte* or **sie beeilte ihn*.

The counterexample you gave is a different word: *herbeieilen*.  This consists of the intransitive verb *eilen*, "to hurry", and the separable prefix *herbei*.  The compound verb is not directly translateable, but it does not mean "hurry up", I think -- *herbei* is probably closest to "hither".  So, *sie eilten herbei* means "they came here in a hurry".

Comment: +1 for covering the distinction of _eilen_ and _sich beeilen_.

Answer (score 15):

In contemporary German [beeilen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/beeilen) is always reflexive in usage.

This was not always the case. When reading literature from the 19. Century you may come across rare sentences like this:

> - Es wird Gewitter, sagte Elisabeth, indem sie ihren Schritt beeilte.<sup>Storm, Theodor: Immensee. Berlin, 1852.</sup>
> - Durch einen Brief des Cardinals Schonberg, aus Rom vom November 1536, wird die Herausgabe beeilt.<sup>Humboldt, Alexander von: Kosmos. Entwurf einer physischen Weltbeschreibung. Bd. 2. Stuttgart u. a., 1847.</sup>

Mostly however *beeilen* was reflexive even then.

Comment: Right, how could I forget about such beautiful usage.

Comment: +1 for the diachronic approach. You could also say something to the question about _eilen_, which is not yet covered in your answer.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: the beautiful answer by phipsgabler already covers that.

Comment: @Takkat I felt that each answer should try to be comprehensive on its own. But that was maybe just a very personal assumption of mine.

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing two different words.

- sich beeilen = to hurry, to hurry up

  - Futur I

  > Klaus wird sich mit dem Frühstück **beeilen.**
  > Klaus will hurry up with breakfast.

  - Präsens

  > Klaus **beeilt** sich mit dem Frühstück.
  > Klaus hurries up with breakfast.

  This is a real reflexive verb, it cannot be used without a reflexive pronoun. The reflexive pronoun is mandatory. And yes, this is always the case. *Sich beeilen* is always a real reflexive verb.
- herbeieilen = to approach, to come running

  - Futur I

  > Der Retter wird bei jedem Wetter **herbeieilen.**
  > The rescuer will come running in any weather.

  - Präsens

  > Der Retter **eilt** bei jedem Wetter **herbei.**
  > The rescuer comes running in any weather.

  This verb isn't a real reflexive verb. It is neither reflexive nor transitive. It is not just possible to use it without reflexive pronoun, it even is not allowed to use it with a reflexive pronoun or a dative or accusative object. It is an intransitive verb.

  You also will have noticed, that *herbeieilen* is a separable verb that has to be used as one word in some tenses and must be split in two parts in some other tenses, but this has nothing to do with being reflexive or transitive.

  *Herbeieilen* is never a reflexive verb and it is never transitive.